# Unable to validate mutli-select input with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm new to Angular, and I struggle with validating a multi select input with [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) attribute.
I want the field to be required, so the user must chose at least one option. However the validation methods Angular have simply doesn't work in my case, Here's what I've tried:

```
<form name="products" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="select-product">Chose product/s</label>
        <select id="select-product" name="selectedProduct" class="form-control"
                required
                multiple
                ng-model="selectedProduct"
                ng-options="product.name for product in products">
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" ng-click="products.selectedProduct.$valid && goToChildrenId()">Next</button>
</form>
```

Even if I chose a product and I can see that the form class switch from `.ng-invalid` to `.ng-valid`, the function `goToChildrenId()` doesn't run.

Also, if I add `{{products.selectedProduct.$valid}}` at the bottom, when I refresh the page I can see "false" for a second but it disappear, why?

If it's relevent, this is the controller:

```
adminCheckout.controller('productsCtrl', function($scope, $http, wpMiniapps, $location, $rootScope){
    $scope.products = [];
    var url = wpMiniapps.routeUrl("getProducts");
    $http.post(url, {}).then(function(res){
        $scope.products = res.data.data;
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });

    $scope.$watch('selectedProduct', function (newVal) {
        $rootScope.globalData.products = newVal;
    });

    $scope.goToChildrenId = function(){
        $location.path('/select-children');
    };
});
```

I searched the web but nothing seems to work in my case.

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable name collision which is causing the problem: the form is named `products` and this ends up as a `$scope` variable. But it collides with `$scope.products = []` from the controller. Simply renaming the form to, e.g., `productsForm` solves the problem:

```
<form name="productsForm" novalidate>
    ...
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" ng-click="productsForm.selectedProduct.$valid && goToChildrenId()">Next</button>
</form>
```